# How to update pom.xml file using jaxb?

Tags: maven, jaxb, xjc

I am working on an application where I have to update the pom.xml file programmatically.
Steps which I am following.

1. Create JAVA POJO from maven XSD (http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd).
2. Using the following program to load pom.xml file in POJO and updated value in the model then updated the same pom.xml file.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
File xml = new File("C:\\DS Designer Forum\\pomfiles\\pom.xml");
Document document = db.parse(xml);
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Model.class);
Binder<Node> binder = jc.createBinder();
Model model = (Model) binder.unmarshal(document);

Dependencies dependencies = model.getDependencyManagement().getDependencies();
if(dependencies != null) {
    for(Dependency dependency : dependencies.getDependency()) {
        if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(dependency.getScope()) && dependency.getScope().contains("provided")) {
           String scope = dependency.getScope().replace("provided", StringUtils.EMPTY);
                dependency.setScope(scope);
        }
    }
}
 
binder.updateXML(model);
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
tf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, false);
Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
t.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(new File("C:\\DS Designer Forum\\pomfiles\\aaaaapom.xml")));
```

getting the following error.

**
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"project"). Expected elements are <{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}project>
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1131)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:60)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:229)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:112)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:95)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:88)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.BinderImpl.associativeUnmarshal(BinderImpl.java:146)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.BinderImpl.unmarshal(BinderImpl.java:117)
at com.sunlife.innovation.update.LoadInfoFromPOMFile.main(LoadInfoFromPOMFile.java:52)
**

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use jaxb to modify a pom.xml? What other options did you consider?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have to update dependencies and other information based on some rules in many applications so to automate this task, I have to load pom.xml file information into POJO and after updating POJO, load POJO data back to pom.xml.

Comment: Why do you need the POJO? Simple updates on an existing xml based on a complex schema can be done with DOM or XSLT easier.

Comment: I thought it would be fast and easy to process as compared to other approaches because using JAXB to load data in POJO and process it, is really easier but also this approach have other limitation as well that I am facing. So thanks, I will check your suggestion. :)

Comment: you can use JDom parser here, to resolve this issue (refer- https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-jdom/?utm_source=self&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=afterpost-related&utm_content=link7)